# Valor decimal MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando inserir valor decimal no banco mysql, queria colocar esses valores por exemplo:

```
1.500,00
```

Milhar, centena e dezena

Qual é o tipo da coluna que devo declarar?

Comment: É para valor monetário ou números reais somente ?

Comment: Você so por armazenar valores números especificando o separador decima que é o ponto `.`. Para deixar no formato desejado é necessário usar uma classe de uma linguaguem de programação.

Comment: numeros reais @gmsantos

Answer (score 17):

O usual é usar `DECIMAL( tamanho, casas )`, que é o tipo projetado para valores exatos com decimal no DB (na falta de qualquer requisito mais específico, é esse o único tipo adequado do DB).

Uma boa alternativa (mas precisa ter domínio do que está fazendo) é usar `INT` e multiplicar os valores por 100 (a mesma escala do número de casas). Nesse segundo caso é bom que o nome do campo reflita isso `valor100` em vez de `valor`, por exemplo. Seria como dizer que você está "guardando a quantidade de centavos".

O tipo que **não deve ser usado** se precisa de valores exatos (monetários é um caso) é o ponto flutuante (double, float etc), que é naturalmente impreciso (encontrar isso num DB pode ser um sinal de que o DBA "faltou nas aulas básicas"). Exceção é para coisas como  mera estatística e outras coisas que sejam meras aproximações, mas isso não é o usual.

Antes de tudo, você tem que converter o valor para um número com pontos no lugar do separador de decimal, o que pode ser feito desta forma:

```
-- Usando DECIMAL(6,2) por exemplo:
INSERT INTO
   minhatabela
SET
   campodecimal = REPLACE( REPLACE( '1.500,00', '.' ,'' ), ',', '.' )
```

ou para inteiros:

```
-- Usando INT(10) por exemplo:
INSERT INTO
   minhatabela
SET
   campointeiro100 = 100 * REPLACE( REPLACE( '1.500,00', '.' ,'' ), ',', '.' )
```

e neste segundo caso, pode usar esta sintaxe para recuperar os dados, invertendo o cálculo:

```
SELECT campointeiro100 / 100 FROM minhatabela
```

A explicação é a seguinte:

- O replace interno troca os pontos por nada, deixando o valor assim: `1500,00`;
- o replace externo troca a vírgula por ponto, deixando o valor assim: `1500.00`, que é o formato que o MySQL espera para números com decimais.
- Tanto o INT quanto o DECIMAL não tem problemas de armazenamento de ponto flutuante, sendo adequados para uso financeiro/monetário.

O INT tem a vantagem de ser muito mais simplificado, e o DECIMAL tem a vantagem de aparecer formatado na tela da maneira desejada, mas apenas utilizando-se ferramentas de consulta SQL.

Como geralmente o uso é feito por meio de uma aplicação, fica muito mais interessante deixar a formatação de tela a cargo da aplicação, por isso o INT geralmente acaba se mostrando mais vantajoso em termos de espaço e velocidade. Lembre-se que neste caso, o `REPLACE` e o `* 100` já podem ser feitos diretamente no lado da aplicação, por uma função própria, deixando o uso do `INT` transparente.

Por outro lado, o `DECIMAL` dá menos trabalho se você precisar mudar o número de casas no futuro. Questão de aplicar o mais conveniente para o caso prático.

Comment: O `INT` guardaria **1500.00**, o que seria mais indicado para trabalhar com formatação e internacionalização transformando em **1,500.00**, **1.500,00**, **1 500,00**, correto?

Comment: @PapaCharlie para dinheiro, por exemplo, se o valor é `1.500,00` eu crio um campo de nome `valor100`  e guardo `150000` centavos. O nome valor100 é um facilitador que eu adotei pra saber que é o inteiro multiplicado por 100. Da mesma forma, eu costumo usar um campo `quantidade1000`, onde "um quilo" do produto seria `1000`, meio litro de combustível é `500`, etc. (a unidade no nome do campo não é necessária, mas é um ótimo lembrete. como o único problema do int que eu conheço é o fato de ter que lembrar o divisor, resolvi assim)

Comment: Quanto à formatação, tem muitas maneiras de fazer, depende mais da linguagem cliente. Mas em praticamente qualquer uma delas uma função para exibir da forma que quiser costuma ser bem simples e eficiente, isso quando a linguagem não tem uma pronta, o que é raro.

Comment: Interessante a estrategia, no seu caso é `INT` certo? Sobre a formatação, a aplicação seria para internacionalizar o mesmo valor, ja que em alguns lugares o milhar é **.**, outros **,**, outros um espaço - como citei acima. Seria mais prático usar um ´printf´ em ter que trocar pontos por virgulas...

Comment: @PapaCharlie tem muitas maneiras, pode pegar valor/100 e valor%100 se quiser separar os centavos do resto, ou pode simplesmente dividir por 100 e usar o ponto da linguagem, se ela já for internacionalizável. De qualquer forma, eu adoto o `int` por ser compatível com qualquer coisa e simples de usar. Em alguns casos, o `decimal` pode ser interessante, se o suporte da linguagem for bom (mas raras vezes uso).

Comment: Estou usando `decimal`, mas com reservas... Gostei do uso do `INT`, vou adotá-la :) TKS Bacco

Comment: @PapaCharlie no mínimo vai ser uma experiência interessante para conhecer os prós e contras :)

Answer (score 12):

No MySQL temos alguns tipos de dados para armazenar números decimais:

**FLOAT** e **DOUBLE**

Ambos representam números com pontos flutuantes.

A diferença entre ambos está em sua precisão e no tamanho em bytes de cada um. O `FLOAT` tem uma acurácia de aproximadamente 7 casas decimais, já o `DOUBLE` até 14, o que resulta do dobro de tamanho em disco se comparado com o `FLOAT`.

**DECIMAL**

Já os números do tipo decimal armazenam um número decimal com **precisão exata**.

No MySQL um tipo decimal pode armazenar no máximo 65 dígitos, sendo esses até 30 dígitos após a casa decimal.

**Mas afinal, qual dos tipos utilizar?**

Depende da sua aplicação. Para aplicações que trabalham com valores monetários, onde a precisão **é** importante, `DECIMAL` é o mais adequado.

Já para aplicações onde a precisão não é importante, ou cálculos científicos, use de `FLOAT` ou `DOUBLE`.

Lembre-se que o MySQL trabalha com números no padrão americano. Logo é preciso converter `,` para `.` como indicado nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37950/4751).

Answer (score 11):

Tipo **`DECIMAL(7,2)`**
A forma mais rápida e fácil.

O `2` indica casas decimais.

O `7` indica quantidade numérica máxima antes da virgula.

Comment: Porque usar decimal ao invés de double?

Comment: @DanielAccorsi por exemplo, eu to inserindo la 1.500,20

ele ta inserindo 1.50

Comment: @gmsantos, o problema de usar double/float para valores monetários é que depois de um valor(alguns milhões) ele começa a perder a precisão dos decimais.

Comment: @Furlan não sei qual tipo você usou, mas geralmente isso ocorre quando você define um tipo decimal com menor capacidade numérica do desejado. O MySql vai automaticamente reduzir o número. Tente aumentar a capacidade no tipo que você escolheu.

Comment: Se para a aplicação for indiferente ter esse nível de precisão decimnal, devo usar o Decimal ?

Comment: @gmsantos float e double trabalham com ponto flutuante, sua precisão não é tão exata quanto o decimal. Lembrando que double e float trabalham através de cálculos internos para chegar no resultado esperado. Já o decimal trabalha de forma "nativa" os valores dos usuários, consequentemente exige menos consumo do servidor. Decimal é ponto fixo, e não flutuante.

Comment: mas qual o tipo exato para eu usar?

Comment: @Furlan use DECIMAL(7,2) - você terá uma margem grande para seus valores. E não perderá em precisão a longo prazo.

Comment: No seu exemplo, o `7` indica a quantidade total de dígitos. `DECIMAL(7,2)` tem 2 casas decimais, e 5 dígitos antes delas.

Answer (score 8):

Armazene o número como `decimal` para não perder a precisão das casas decimais em valores monetários. Para inserir/atualizar faça uma conversão do número formatado `1.500,00` primeiro remova todos os pontos e por último substitua a virgula por ponto no final ele ficará assim: `1500.00`. Em um select pode usar o código abaixo

```
SELECT concat('R$ ', format(15000, 2)) as valor;
```

saida:

```
R$ 15,000.00
```

[**Exemplo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/47120)

Baseado em:

[mysql - format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

[SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939326/number-format-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o valor Decimal do MySQL com seu valor indicado como 10,2

```
decimal(10,2)
```

Comment: Saudações Rodrigo, isso já não foi respondido nas outras respostas?

Comment: Opa, saudações Anderson. De fato foi respondido, porém, apontei uma solução em se tratando de valor monetário que me foi útil, apenas pensei que seria útil para quem fosse ler também.

Comment: Poderia completar a resposta justificando o porquê dos valores 10 e 2?

Comment: 10,2 por conta de duas casas decimais pós vírgula, sendo que para a exibição do mesmo em uma consulta poderíamos utilizar o seguinte comando FORMAT(IMO_VALOR_ALUGUEL, 2, 'de_DE') AS Alugar que foi o que já utilizei em uma situação no meu atual emprego.