# Retorno de subtração no postgres

Tags: postgresql

possuo uma tabela com um campo chamado VALOR double precision, e uma função que retorna outra dado também double precision, o que acontece é que 
se eu fizer

select (VALOR - funcao()) as resultado
sendo que nesse caso tanto o VALOR quanto o resultado da função são iguais, 
o resultado fica com valor 2.27373675443232e-013

achei muito estranho e não estou sabendo o que fazer, já realizei alguns testes
com conversões e arredondamentos e nada

alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa estar acontecendo???

Comment: Quantas casas decimais você precisa exibir? esse número aí está em notação cientifica.

Comment: Preciso somente de duas... Porém os dois, tanto a coluna valor está com valor de 1609.86 e o retorno da função está sendo 1609.86 sendo assim o resultado seria 0.0 e não esse NR em notação científica

Comment: obtive uma resposta no stack em ingles

double precision is a lossy data type. The decimal representation you see is only an approximation of the internal binary value. The kind of "unexpected" mismatch you see is to be expected when calculating with floating-point numbers.

You could work with a loss-less type like numeric to avoid this. (And possibly round to a reasonable number of fractional digits.)

Start by reading the Postgres manual on numeric data types and at least one of the many articles out there about floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: vou tentar alterar os campos para numeric e testar...

Comment: Você está usando double para guardar valores que representam dinheiro?

Comment: sim, tanto dinheiro quanto percentuais...

Comment: Double tem problemas de arredondamento ainda mais se for para representar dinheiro, tem hora que os centavos simplesmente mudam. O ideal é mudar para numeric ou bigint. [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37947/91) e [essa outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/91) tem mais detalhes sobre o problema de double/float/real com valores monetários.

Comment: realizei uma nova pergunta, relacionada com a alteracao dos meus campos, tenho algumas tabelas ja e gostaria de alterar todas as colunas de uma so vez, existe a possibilidade?? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103349/alterar-tipo-campo-de-todas-as-tabelas