# alterar tipo campo de todas as tabelas

Tags: postgresql

existe alguma maneira de percorrer as tabelas de uma banco, alterando todas as colunas de um determinado tipo?

tipo utilizado agora DOUBLE PRECISION
tipo desejado NUMERIC

Comment: qual banco de dados? mysql, sql, oracle?

Comment: postgres..

consegui bolar uma funcao

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AlteraTipoDoubleNumeric()
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    recTables RECORD;
    recFields RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- SELECIONA AS TABELAS E ESQUEMAS
    FOR recTables IN SELECT n.nspname, relname FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c     JOIN 
    pg_catalog.pg_roles r ON r.oid = c.relowner LEFT JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE relkind = 'r'
    AND n.nspname ='public' --NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast',     'information_schema') 
    LOOP
    FOR recFields IN SELECT a.attname, pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as tipodedado FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c on c.oid = a.attrelid
    WHERE a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped AND c.relname = recTables.relname and pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) = 'double precision'
    LOOP
        raise notice '%, %, %', recTables.relname, recFields.attname, recFields.tipodedado;
        execute 'alter table ' || recTables.relname || ' alter column ' || recFields.attname || ' type numeric (10, 6) using ' || recFields.attname || '::numeric';
    END LOOP;
    END LOOP; 
    RETURN 'Acabou!!';
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Comment: porem esbarrei nas dependencias nas views... :(

    ERRO:  não pode alterar tipo de uma coluna utilizada por uma visão ou regra

Comment: Gere o script das views , drope as views , aplique o alter table , regere as views , reze .... https://www.savepoint.blog.br/2015/11/09/gerando-o-ddl-de-todas-as-views-de-um-esquema-no-postgresql/....