# Alterar . por , com PHP ou MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela que salva dados que vem de um txt e tenho um campo valor e ele salva no formato: `5.00`

Como altero no banco ou no PHP para `5,00`?

Ou seja, trocando o `.` (ponto)  pela `,` (virgula).

**Código**:

```
<?php
include 'includes\head.php';
include "conexao.php";
  $data_mes = $_POST['mes'];
  $data_ano = $_POST['ano'];
// Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
$_UP['pasta'] = 'uploads/';
// Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
$_UP['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 4; // 2Mb
// Array com as extensões permitidas
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif','txt','pdf');
// Renomeia o arquivo? (Se true, o arquivo será salvo como .jpg e um nome único)
$_UP['renomeia'] = true;
// Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
$_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
$_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do PHP';
$_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especifiado no HTML';
$_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
$_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';
// Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0) {
  die("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:" . $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
  exit; // Para a execução do script
}
// Caso script chegue a esse ponto, não houve erro com o upload e o PHP pode continuar
// Faz a verificação da extensão do arquivo
$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
  echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: txt,pdf,jpg, png ou gif";
  exit;
}
// Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']) {
  echo "O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 2Mb.";
  exit;
}
// O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar movê-lo para a pasta
// Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
  // Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
  $nome_final = 'tefonia.txt';
  //$nome_final = md5(time()).'.txt';
} else {
  // Mantém o nome original do arquivo
  $nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
}


// Depois verifica se é possível mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {
  // Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe uma mensagem e um link para o arquivo
 echo "<center><h1>Upload efetuado com sucesso! <br></h1>";
 echo '<div align="center">';
 echo '<img src="images\logo.jpg">';
 echo '</div>';
 echo '<br><a href="uploadtxt.php" class="btn btn-primary">Voltar</a></center>';
} else {
  // Não foi possível fazer o upload, provavelmente a pasta está incorreta
  echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, tente novamente";
}

$filename = "uploads/tefonia.txt";
$arq = fopen ($filename, "r");
$read = fread ($arq, filesize ($filename) );

$separador = ";"; // O que separa os resultados no arquivos TXT ?

$array = explode($separador, $read);
$conta = count($array);

for ($i=0; $i < $conta; $i++) {

    $sql_conta = "INSERT INTO contas_txt (contas_txt_id, contas_txt_nome, contas_txt_celular, contas_txt_data,
                contas_txt_hora, contas_txt_desc, contas_txt_cod, contas_txt_fixo,
                contas_txt_tel_dest, contas_txt_minutos, contas_txt_vazio1, contas_txt_vazio2, contas_txt_valor,contas_txt_mes,contas_txt_ano) 
                VALUES (NULL, '" . $array[$i] . "', '" . @$array[$i + 1] . "', '" . @$array[$i + 2] . "',
                    '" . @$array[$i + 3] . "', '" . @$array[$i + 4] . "', '" . @$array[$i + 5] . "',
                    '" . @$array[$i + 6] . "', '" . @$array[$i + 7] . "', '" . @$array[$i + 8] . "',
                    '" . @$array[$i + 9] . "', '" . @$array[$i + 10] . "', '" . @$array[$i + 11] . "', '".$data_mes. "', '".$data_ano."')";
   $resultado_conta = mysql_query($sql_conta) 
    or die(mysql_error());

   $sql_valor = "UPDATE contas_txt SET contas_txt_valor = replace( contas_txt_valor, '.', ',' )";
              $resultado_replace = mysql_query($sql_valor) 
              or die(mysql_error());


 //  $sql_celular = "INSERT INTO celular (id,celular) VALUES (NULL,'" . @$array[$i + 1] . "')";
 //  $resultado_celular = mysql_query($sql_celular) 
 //    or die(mysql_error());



    $i = $i + 11;


} 

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Não altere no banco. Ou salve no banco com o tipo DECIMAL, ou multiplique por 100 e salve como INT. Na hora de exibir, aí sim troque os pontos por vírgula, com `str_replace`, no PHP.

Comment: Não entendi bem,segue meu codigo. Onde faria essa multiplicação ?

Comment: @bfavaretto porque não poderia salvar em FLOAT?

Comment: @Inkeliz Poder, pode, mas arrisca [causar problemas de precisão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37947/valor-decimal-mysql).

Comment: @bfavaretto não sabia desta diferença. :| Há alguma maneira de converter de float para decimal (mantendo mesmo valor), ou é caminho sem volta?

Comment: @Inkeliz Se você só armazena e tem poucas casas decimais, geralmente o arredondamento padrão te resolve. Mas quando você começa a agrupar dados e fazer cálculos, o erro vai acumulando. Mas depende muito do que você precisa fazer, é importante evitar floats principalmente ao lidar com moedas. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/006e5/2

Comment: Otacio, é mais simples definir a coluna como decimal no banco.

Comment: É dei uma pesquisa rápida por aqui. Desculpe por 'atrapalhar' o tópico com um assunto 'nada haver'. No caso não utilizo os dados para efetuar soma/subtração, apenas para ordena-los e mostra-los. Agora existe algum problema de performance nisto (vs decimal), mesmo usando index?

Comment: Otacio, por favor não desfaça as melhorias que outros usuários fizerem no seu post (formatação, gramática e remoção de saudações). Se quiser saber mais sobre o ***modelo wiki*** do [pt.so] pode conferir o **[tour]**. Obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No PHP str_replace

```
$vl_unitario = "3.00";
$vl_unitario = str_replace('.', ',', $vl_unitario);
//$vl_unitario = "3,00";
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Obrigado,pela explicação.