# Converter Valores Moeda para Decimal?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho três valores cujo estão sendo passado via POST para ser gravado no banco, eu tento gravar os dados mas porém ele grava com valores errados. Os dados estão assim:

```
"valor_liquido": "R$1.000,00",
"valor_bruto": "R$1.000,00",
"valor_desconto": "R$0,00"
```

No banco de dados eles são gravados como *1.00,1.00 e 0.00*

Usei o str_replace para remover a vírgula, mas não deu certo.

```
$estoque->valorbruto = str_replace(',','.',substr($v1,2));
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo de campo de campo na tabela? Decimal (9,2) por ex?

Comment: Mas porque não usa o campo float do banco de dados, pra gravar certinho?

Comment: Os campos são decimal(13,2)

Comment: O Float ficaria melhor?

Comment: seu str_replace não está removendo o separador de milhar... isso que está causando o problema.

Comment: Resolvido. Vlw.

Comment: Float não é adequado para armazenar valores monetarios, veja [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37952/91) e [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/91)

Comment: Vou dar uma lida nisto @rray sempre usei o float, acho que estou errado rsrsrrs obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Apenas esqueceu de remover o ponto.

Deveria ser assim

```
$estoque->valorbruto = str_replace('.', '', str_replace(',','.',substr($v1,2)));
```

A lógica aqui é primeiramente converter vírgula por ponto e então remover quaisquer outros pontos existentes.

## Unidade de milhar

Na computação não existe marcadores para unidades de milhar. Essa marcação é meramente visual. O ponto representa decimal, por isso obtém resultados inesperados como o que apresentou na pergunta.

## Dica: casas decimais

Mais uma dica, pense bem se realmente quer manter valor monetário com apenas 2 casas decimais. Numa divisão pode ter .333333333, por exemplo.

Estaria “comendo” 3333333, são 7 casas. Num sistema com muitas transações isso é um rombo enorme nas contas. Mas não é obrigatório pois isso varia com cada business logic. Apenas esteja ciente na modelagem de um modelo de negócio que exija maior precisão.

Answer (score 1):

O SQL Não trabalha com virgula. Ele separa o decimal usando um ponto(.).
Primeiro vc deve remover o ponto da string q recebe e depois substituir a virgula por ponto.

```
$valorFormatado = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $valorRecebido));
```

Simplificando:
1º passo remover o ponto do milhar.
ex: `$valorRecebidoSemMilhar = str_replace('.', '', $valorRecebido);`
2º substituir a virgula do decimal por ponto.
ex: `$valorCorreto = str_replace(',', '.', $valorRecebidoSemMilhar);`