# Truncar numeros numa coluna Mysql

Tags: mysql, query

Quero deixar todos os numeros que são inseridos no meu banco com no maximo 1 casa decimal depois da virgula sem arredondamento 
Ex: 3.2567 = 3.2
Quero saber se posso truncar a coluna todas do banco ( ja tentei mas não consegui), usando:
Select truncate (coluna,1).

Comment: "Tentei mas não consegui" é meio vago. A sintaxe é `TRUNCATE( coluna, casas)` mesmo (ao menos na versão 5.5 já era presente). Qual o problema que teve? Da forma como descrito, seu problema não pode ser reproduzido.

Comment: Qual o tipo da coluna?

Comment: Você quer dar update na coluna?

Comment: Seria isso que você quer? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37947/valor-decimal-mysql

Comment: Tentei truncate (coluna, 1). Essa coluna esta como INT

Comment: Dar truncate (coluna, 1) em coluna de Numero inteiro?

Comment: Eu fiz assim e deu certo: round (sum (coluna/1000),1) as total. Os numeros estão com somente ima casa após a virgula. Não sei se foi muito gambiarra mas deu certo.

Comment: @Leo Caracciolo sim inteiro.

Comment: Me soa estranho inteiro com decimal, INT or INTEGER Um inteiro de tamanho normal